# When validate Q-Select with vee-validate 4, the use-input attributes is not working and don know why the value appearing twice

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vee-validate

Here is my code

```
           <Field
              name="options"
              rules="required"
              v-slot="{ errorMessage, value, field }"
            >
              <q-select
                filled
                dense
                use-chips
                use-input
                multiple
                :model-value="value"
                :options="state.options"
                label="Filled"
                v-bind="field"
                :error-message="errorMessage"
                :error="!!errorMessage"
              />
            </Field>
```

How do I use the use-input attributes and remove the double value that display in the select field? Please help thank you.

Q-Select-validation

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved Thanks to logaretm.

Because v-bind="field" is doing a bunch of even listening which conflicts with that component. The field object doesn't know the kind of the component/element so it tries to cover as much cases as possible by listing to input, change, update:model-value events. In that component case it is possible it emits both input and update:model-value because of the text input inside it.

You can fix it by being selective of what events should change the value with handleChange.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-v4-quasar-framework-gbma2c?file=src%2FApp.vue